# Derivation of volume of regular rhombicosidodecahedron?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, volume, polyhedra

I understand how to find the surface area of a regular rhombicosidodecahedron. The formula given on Wikipedia is simple to use. Surface area is simply the sum of the areas of each face, which I can easily derive from plane trigonometry:
$$
\begin{multline}
A = 20\left(\frac12\cdot3\cdot\frac12 
\cdot \tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}\right)a^2 \\
+ 30\left(\frac12\cdot4\cdot\frac12 
\cdot \tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\right)a^2 \\
+ 12\left(\frac12\cdot5\cdot\frac12 
\cdot \tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)}\right)a^2
\end{multline}
$$

which simplifies to
$$
A = \left(30+5\sqrt3+3\sqrt{25+10\sqrt5}\right)a^2 
$$

But how would I go about deriving the formula for the volume of a regular rhombicosidodecahedron? On Wikipedia it is given as the following:
$$ 
V = \frac{60+29\sqrt5}{3}a^3
$$

My thought process was, find the coordinates of each vertex in 3D space given an edge length $a$, assuming it is centered on the origin, then calculate the volume of each pyramid formed with the center by each face. But then that means I would have to know how to find the coordinates of each vertex, which I do not know how to do.

How then would I find those coordinates? Or, if that's a needlessly complex or even incorrect way to go about it, how do I derive this formula then?

Comment: Wikipedia's ["Rhombicosidodecahedron" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates) gives coords; figuring out which is which is a nice challenge. Alternatively, position a regular pentagon on the $xy$-plane with a vertex at the origin and its center on, say, the $x$-axis; let the vertices neighboring the origin be $A$ and $B$. Then "all you have to do" is find $C$ and $D$ such that $|OA|=|OB|=|OC|=|OD|$, $OA\perp OC$, $OB\perp OD$, and $\triangle COD$ is equilateral. From there, you can find the center and then also the volumes of the various pyramids.

Comment: @Blue - That configuration of pentagon-square-triangle-square is flexible. You also need symmetry; $C$ and $D$ should be each other's reflection along $AB$ (equivalently the $y$ axis).

Comment: @Patrick - You don't need all the coordinates. You just need enough of them to find the volume of one pentagonal pyramid, one square pyramid, and one triangular pyramid.

Comment: After finding $A,B,C,D$, you can find the polyhedron's centre (i.e. the pyramids' apex) as the point in the $x,z$ plane equidistant from all five vertices $O,A,B,C,D$.

Comment: @Blue I saw the list, yes, but I don't know how they got those. But it seems like what you're asking is to actually find vectors OC and OD which have an angle of 60 degrees between them, given that they are perpendicular to OA and OB, respectively. One of the four solutions should have the vectors oriented in the proper directions. Is that correct?

Comment: @mr_e_man: *"That configuration of pentagon-square-triangle-square is flexible."* Thanks for the clarification. My intention was more along the lines "find *an appropriate* $C$ and $D$ ...", but even that could've been clearer. (I'll blame the character-count limit. :)

Comment: Actually you can just take vertex coordinates from the [pentagonal cupola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_cupola). That should make things easier, because of the regular decagon. And the centre must be on the cupola's axis of symmetry.

Comment: @PatrickO'Brien: *"One of the four solutions should have the vectors oriented in the proper directions. Is that correct?"* ... Correct. (Well, actually, *two* of the solutions will work, giving the polyhedral center either *above* or *below* the $xy$-plane.)

Comment: The cupola's coordinates are $$\frac{1}{2\sin\tfrac\pi5}(\cos k\tfrac{2\pi}5,\sin k\tfrac{2\pi}5,0),\quad k\in\mathbb Z\bmod5$$ (for the pentagon) and $$\frac{1}{2\sin\tfrac\pi{10}}(\cos(k+\tfrac12)\tfrac{2\pi}{10},\sin(k+\tfrac12)\tfrac{2\pi}{10},h),\quad k\in\mathbb Z\bmod10$$ (for the decagon), where $h$ must be determined by the slant edge length. Then the rhombicosidodecahedron's centre is some point $(0,0,z)$ equidistant from a pentagon vertex and a decagon vertex.